# Update Query For ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have four columns

| id | fisrt_name | last_name | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | A | B | C |
| 303 | A | B | C |
| 207 | A | B | C |
| 55 | X | Y | Z |
| 67 | X | Y | Z |
| 200 | X | Y | Z |

Basically FN, LN and city are same but the ids are different for these same values. I want to UPDATE the Ids of the duplicate rows as same, shown in table below using oracle sql developer. The id can be update to either of the three but it should become same for all the three duplicate rows.

| id | fisrt_name | last_name | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | A | B | C |
| 101 | A | B | C |
| 101 | A | B | C |
| 55 | X | Y | Z |
| 55 | X | Y | Z |
| 55 | X | Y | Z |

I tried this

```
UPDATE TABLE T1 SET
T1.ID = ID
WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT ROWID FROM(
SELECT ROWID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, CITY ORDER BY ADR_LINE_1) AS RN, ID, CITY 
FROM TABLE
WHERE (first_name,last_name,city) IN (first_name,last_name,city
from table 
group by first_name,last_name,city
having count(distinct id) >= 2)) WHERE RN = 1);
```

It updates the desired rows but with the same ids not with what I want.

Comment: Your query is far more complicated than it needs to be. You have two (or more?!) levels of `SELECT` queries. You should refactor it to use a CTE and a `JOIN` instead of having all of those `WHERE x IN ( SELECT ... )`.

Comment: Also, please use a better placeholder name than `TABLE`, because that's a keyword in SQL which makes it harder to read your query.

Comment: sure appreciate the recommendation on that table thing, it was just to refer to any table. But is there any way this can be achieved using rownum?

Comment: Left justified SQL is just so hard to read, and to write...

Comment: @jarlh I think it's the lack of any indentation, along with half of it being in uppercase before the caps lock comes off at line 7, that makes it hard to read. Also the construction `IN (first_name,last_name,city from table` doesn't make any sense - perhaps there is a missing `select` keyword.

Comment: Why would you want exact duplicates in the table?  Why not just delete all but the lowest id?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way - join your table to the result of an aggregate query and update (group by fn, ln, city, filter out the groups with a single id, and select min(id) in the remaining groups, then use that to update).

Set up the test case:

```
create table my_table (id, first_name, last_name, city) as
  select 101, 'A', 'B', 'C' from dual union all
  select 303, 'A', 'B', 'C' from dual union all
  select 207, 'A', 'B', 'C' from dual union all
  select  55, 'X', 'Y', 'Z' from dual union all
  select  67, 'X', 'Y', 'Z' from dual union all
  select 200, 'X', 'Y', 'Z' from dual union all
  select 333, 'D', 'F', 'G' from dual
;

Table MY_TABLE created.
```

Update:

```
update
( select t.id, g.min_id
  from   my_table t
         inner join
         ( select min(id) as min_id, first_name, last_name, city
           from   my_table
           group  by first_name, last_name, city
           having min(id) != max(id)
         ) g
         using (first_name, last_name, city)
)
set id = min_id
where id != min_id
;

4 rows updated.
```

Check the result:

```
select * from my_table;

        ID FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME  CITY      
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       101 A          B          C         
       101 A          B          C         
       101 A          B          C         
        55 X          Y          Z         
        55 X          Y          Z         
        55 X          Y          Z         
       333 D          F          G
```

NOTE: If ID may be null, that will require a bit of additional handling (but, the column ***should be*** NOT NULL.... is it?)

Comment: Id is not null, though the other columns are null for some of the ids

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `MIN()` Analytic Function with grouping by repeating three columns (`first_name`, `last_name`, `city`) through a `MERGE` Statement such as

```
MERGE INTO tab t1
USING ( SELECT MIN(id) OVER (PARTITION BY first_name, last_name, city) AS new_id
          FROM tab t ) t2
   ON ( t1.rowid = t2.rowid )                 
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t1.id = t2.new_id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bc50adbd485f279a219a83039f8ce071)</kbd>

Comment: Can you explain how this rowid match works over the partition

Comment: You're welcome @Rishu Tripathi .  Indeed, we don't usually use rowid values within the SQL statements. Because, they are just physical addresses, and change as some disk operations applied such as Move, Shrink .. In this case, no problem even if the change occurs, since we remain within the same table for the main and subqueries, and practical to ise as having unique values.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a correlated subquery:

```
update t1 
set id = (
    select min(id) 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.first_name = t.first_name and t1.lastname = t.lastname and t1.city = t.city
)
where id > (
    select min(id) 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.first_name = t.first_name and t1.lastname = t.lastname and t1.city = t.city
)
```

This query would take advantage of an index on `(firstname, lastname, city, id)` - although updating the rows will require updating the index too...